# PySerial: Data Corruption in first 256 Bytes

Tags: python, pyserial

I'm using pyserial to process some data which is transmitted over a Serial interface with 1.25MBaud. I'm using a very simple thread to collect the data:

```
class SerialReadThread(StoppableThread):

    def __init__(self, port):
        super(SerialReadThread, self).__init__()
        self.serial = s.Serial(
            port=port,
            baudrate=1250000, # 1.25 MBaud
            bytesize=s.EIGHTBITS,
            parity=s.PARITY_NONE,
            stopbits=s.STOPBITS_ONE,
            timeout=0.5 # Do not wait longer than a half second for next message
        )
        self.data = []

    def run(self):
        # Discard old Buffer Data
        self.serial.flushInput()
        #self.serial.read(256)
        while not self.stopped():
            data = self.serial.read(64)
            self.data.append(data)
            log.debug(":".join("{:02x}".format(ord(c)) for c in data))
```

If I read and process the data I get always one wrong byte in the first 256 Bytes. One of the messages which are normally 8 Byte is 9 Byte long and I have no idea where this additional byte is coming from. If I start the sender after starting the receiver, no wrong bytes are transmitted. The only solution so far which works is to comment in the line `self.serial.read(256)`. After that, no errors occur even if I read a lot of data.

Is there another solution than just skipping the first messages?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably just some noise on the line. Usually for baudrates more than 115200 you need 2 stop bits, so it will be:

```
stopbits=s.STOPBITS_TWO
```

Comment: I do not think that noise. Why should there be noise during the first 256 bytes and never after that? And I can't just set stopbits to two, this would not match the settings which are specified by the sender.

Comment: There are such things like parasitic inductance(I) and capacitance(C) and because of it noise is bigger at the start of transmission when line is starting to change I and C by changing voltage. Basically there will be bigger oscillations on line at the start of transmission. To proof it or disproof you need digital oscilloscope. But in any case by my experience you need 2 stop bits at such baudrate

Comment: You also can try to buy a good hi quality USB cord, but no guaranty that it gonna work because problem might be in chip's peripheral.